# Does initialization inside the loop affect speed?

Tags: c

There are 2 code examples, which one will work faster?

```
for(;;) {
   auto time = generator;
}
```

second option

```
auto time; // int time, string time, char time etc

for(;;) {
   time = generator;
}
```

`generator` is something big and incomprehensible, it doesn’t matter.

The important thing is whether the initialization of the variable auto in the loop or behind the loop affects it or does it not matter?

Comment: A definition like `auto time;` is invalid. Besides that it really matters *what* `generator` might be, and what its destructor does (as the first variant will destruct `time` each time in the loop, but not in the second).

Comment: auto is all kinds of types that can be, if at least one type slows down speed then what type is it?

Comment: @user No, that's not what `auto` does.

Comment: Suppose `auto` is all types; don't carp at this

Comment: `auto` does different things in C and C++, by editing your tags you changed the semantics *a lot*. And in C the `auto` keyword really doesn't mean the same thing as in C++, and `auto time;` is *still* invalid in modern C.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The second option will work faster if the type does not collapse like the first?

Comment: @user That depends on whether the assignment operator has been overloaded - and what logic is in the assignment operator.

Comment: And in both C and C++ it still matters what the type really is. It actually matters *more* in C++ since it depends on what operators and constructors you might have overloaded (and any possible destructor as I already mentioned).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so in order to avoid mistakes it is better to use option 2 right?
(C++)

Comment: @user What "mistakes"?

Comment: errors in the speed of the program, since the first option can slow it down.

Comment: But there's also the general "rule" to define variables as close to their use as possible. Do you really need to use this variable `time` outside of the loop? Do you really need it at all, can't you use `generator` directly inside the loop? What are you actually doing inside the loop? What is the actual problem you need to solve (plain curiosity is okay, but this is really to context-sensitive to answer in its current form).

Comment: @user Poor performance is not usually considered an "error" because it doesn't affect the correctness of a program. And it sounds like you're trying to micro-optimize your program. Don't do that. Compiler designers are smarter than all of us put together - and modern C++ compilers will rewrite and reorganize your code into something that's completely unrecognizable to the original program structure or flow in order to squeeze every drop of performance out of your CPU.

Comment: If you refuse to tell us anything about the type in question, the only way to check is to profile both versions. It is entirely posible that compiler can optimize it to same code in both cases and there will be no difference. Also you should make sure you are using move semantics instead of copy semantics wherever possible.

Comment: @Dai I like your comments, maybe you're right the compiler does everything himself.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I won’t deal with micro optimization anymore.
i believe in compiler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user, it won't affect the performance. In fact, both the snippets will generate the same set of instructions. We can judge the performance based on the instructions generated.

**Tip:** No need to specify the **storage class specifier as auto**. By default, all the variables declared inside the function without the storage-class specifier will be considered as "auto"

Snippet 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int generator = 1;
int main(){
    auto time;
    for(;;){
        time = generator;
        printf("%d", generator);
    }
}
```

Assembly instructions :

```
000000000000064a <main>:
 64a:   55                      push   %rbp
 64b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 64e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 652:   8b 05 b8 09 20 00       mov    0x2009b8(%rip),%eax        # 201010 <generator>
 658:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
 65b:   8b 05 af 09 20 00       mov    0x2009af(%rip),%eax        # 201010 <generator>
 661:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
 663:   48 8d 3d 9a 00 00 00    lea    0x9a(%rip),%rdi        # 704 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 66a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 66f:   e8 ac fe ff ff          callq  520 <printf@plt>
 674:   eb dc                   jmp    652 <main+0x8>
 676:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Snippet2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int generator = 1;
int main(){
    for(;;){
        auto time = generator;
        printf("%d", generator);
    }
}
```

Assembly instructions:

```
64a:   55                      push   %rbp
 64b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 64e:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
 652:   8b 05 b8 09 20 00       mov    0x2009b8(%rip),%eax        # 201010 <generator>
 658:   89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
 65b:   8b 05 af 09 20 00       mov    0x2009af(%rip),%eax        # 201010 <generator>
 661:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
 663:   48 8d 3d 9a 00 00 00    lea    0x9a(%rip),%rdi        # 704 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 66a:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 66f:   e8 ac fe ff ff          callq  520 <printf@plt>
 674:   eb dc                   jmp    652 <main+0x8>
 676:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```